Render Error View config getter callback for component RCTModalHostView must be a function (received 'undefined')
I am working on a mobile application in React native (using Expo [SDK :~51.0.18])
Note : I am using Expo router to handle all routing in my project.
I am attempting to integrate this new SDK (Lean tech) into my app for bank connection (GCC region). This package uses react-native-webview
I have followed all the instructions in the tutorial as such  :
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Button, useTheme} from 'react-native-paper';
// @ts-ignore
import LinkSDK from "lean-react-native";

const Screen: React.FC = () => {
 
  const theme = useTheme();
  const styles = createStyles(theme);
  const Lean = useRef(null)

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

          <LinkSDK
              ref={Lean}
              appToken="xxxxxx-6e5e-xxxx-xx58-bx6xd9fxxxxx"
              version="@latest"
              country="ArabEmirates"
              sandbox
          />
          <Button style={styles.button} mode="contained" textColor="#013511"  onPress={() => Lean.current.connect({ customer_id: "xxxxxxx" })}>
              Link Bank Account
          </Button>


      </View>
  );
};

Whenever i click the button to create the connection, I get the following error :

I am posting this question to see if the issue is with me using Expo or if i need to do any additional setups (or linking) ? I did not follow the Pod install instruction as i am testing on an android device.

I want to thank everyone who contributed with an answer to help me solve this. I had to dig into the SDK and modify the Modal and webview code as @fengeljardt mentioned. It was a problem with modal host view when it interacts with the webview component and a compatibility issue with Expo.

Here is the documentation that talks about webview crash issues on Android, hope it helps https://docs.leantech.me/v2.0-KSA/docs/react-native#webview-crashes-on-android

I tried that and it doesn't work. still throws same error

Do they have semi-open source lib you can look at? This looks like a problem with modal host view when it interacts with the webview component.

Maybe play around with how the modal is rendering in react-native, it could change the trace at least.


https://docs.leantech.me/v2.0-KSA/docs/android#presentation-options
Also try running the app outside of a navigation screen. Maybe it behaves differently
Try debugging with a step debugger


Try debugging the native crash.


On android studio use the step debugger.
Add a pause on exceptions.
It should break when attempting to load the component
If not, you will need to find their package within node_modules and add inspection to their assets. You may have to decompile their app to see the source of the problem. At this point...it's worth asking them questions + asking for open source.

Second step is to reach out to them since there code looks closed source.

You could ask them politely to publish their UI components and native source code.
Tell them the issue, mention your react-native version and expo versions.
React Native projects are meant for the community and contribution / feedback from the community is important to gauge health of an SDK.

Also with react-native error messages, it's better to post the console output instead of the redscreen/warning screens so we can see the full message.

Just a possible solution but not sure.
Use React.forwardRef if Needed. In some cases, using React.forwardRef might help ensure the ref is correctly passed down to the native component.
const LinkSDKRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <LinkSDK {...props} ref={ref} />
));

<LinkSDKRef
  ref={Lean}
  appToken="xxxxxx-6e5e-xxxx-xx58-bx6xd9fxxxxx"
  version="@latest"
  country="ArabEmirates"
  sandbox
/>;

